# Regex with can be numerous ----- and must newline after the string

Tags: c#, regex

How would a regex look like when I search for this string:

```
before CAN be many comment lines --------"Encrypted" after must come a newline.
```

this does not seem to work:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^[-]*$[Encrypted][\n]");
```

what do I wrong?

Comment: Try this free regular expression tool: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you're searching for is not entirely clear to me, nor are the rest of the contents you're searching in, but if you're **really** just looking for "Encrypted" directly followed by **only** a newline then this is all you need to do:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"Encrypted\n")
```

**EDIT**

Ok, comments seem to suggest that you're looking for zero or more occurences of "-", followed by "Encrypted", followed by newline. In that case the following will work.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"-*Encrypted\n");
```

If there should be at least one "-" before "Encrypted", it will be

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"-+Encrypted\n");
```

Comment: Comment symbols then Encrypted then a newline, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the square brackets and move the dollar `$` to the end of the pattern. Ie:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^-*Encrypted$");
```

The square brackets is like an `Or` statement. So `[Encrypted]` is the same as saying: `'E' or 'n' or 'c' or 'r'.... or 'd'`.

The dollar symbol matches the end of the string.

Comment: I have this: --Encrypted newline....

your regex does not work, match.Success is false

Comment: @Sanju, Please provide some sample text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically regex for c# but i thing you must not put the ^ because -'s are not at the begining of the line. And what the $ is doing in the middle.

So i would do in PCRE regex:

```
/-+"Encrypted" *\n/
```

That match one or more - followed by "Encryption" followed by 0 or more space followed by newline.

Answer (score 0):

@Sanju

does this work :P

Regex pattern = new Regex(@"-*Encrypted\n");

for me it did! You have to remove the "^" char